# Call to where function on model with a hash only doesn't find DB record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to retrieve a record using Rails `.where()` function on an ActiveRecord model.

The function will only return a record if the clause is defined in a string, so:

**Returns single record as expected**

`Model.where("business_id = 16")`

`Model.where("business_id = :business_id", {business_id: 16})`

(for which I see the SQL: `WHERE (business_id = 16)`)

**Returns empty array**

`Model.where({:business_id => 16})`

(for which I see `WHERE model.business_id = 16`)

`Model.where({business_id: 16})`

`Model.where(:business_id => 16)`

The database record exists and the field we are querying on is defined as an integer there.

What is going on?

---

Tests run from a `binding.pry`

**Version Data**

Rails 3.2.21

ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-darwin13.0]

Pry version 0.10.1 on Ruby 2.1.5

Comment: Can you post the result of a `Model.where({:business_id => 16}).to_sql` commant? and please specify the Rails version.

Comment: Perhaps you can run that query from the Rails console with SQL logging enabled and share the SQL query.

Comment: What is that you mean by `doesn't work` ? Does that give an error or giving an empty result or nil result?

Comment: edited with definition of 'doesn't work' :-)

Comment: Did you try running the same in IRB. I guess this has something to do with pry...

Comment: I tested using binding.pry as well. All the above conditional selects are giving me a result. Not a pry issue as well. Something weird is happening here. Version of ruby, rails, and pry?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna version data added

Comment: I don't see any issue. Will the query be just where on the model or are there any joins? Names of columns in that model? Just trying to get as much info as possible. I definitely don't see anything skeptical from the data given here.

Comment: tbh, I think this might be a problem in our app, which I can't share easily as it's proprietary code, I had assumed I had made some error in my code, but that isn't the case, but it's been useful to eliminate that! this question would probably best be deleted really, I've asked the same question on our internal system :-)

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you have written is perfectly fine. You just please run the following line on rails console.

`Model.find_by_business_id(16)`

I think it will return nothing. There is no record with `business_id` = 16

Comment: there definitely is a business record 16, as the question states, `Model.where("business_id = :business_id", {business_id: 16})` returns a record as expected

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you use the **where()** and pass the arguments, it will take those as a hash(key-value pair). So you don't need to pass like this

Model.where({:business_id => 16})

You should pass something like this
**in rails 3**

```
Model.where(:business_id => 16)
```

**in rails 4**

```
Model.where(business_id: 16)
```

Also you can use rails 3 syntax for where clause in rails 4 also.

Comment: `Model.where(:business_id => 16)` is the same as `Model.where({:business_id => 16})` I don't see any difference.

Comment: see edited question, these examples were tried and also failed